# How do I undelete a managed object marked for deletion in Core Data?

Tags: core-data, synchronization

To create a managed object in Core Data:

```
NSManagedObject *aManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee"
inManagedObjectContext:aContext];
```

To delete a managed object, send a message to its managed object context.

```
[aContext deleteObject:aManagedObject];
```

That method sends a message to aManagedObject

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion
```

Here's my problem. I'm syncing this data with an external database. I have an attribute named "deleted". When an object is first "deleted" I want to set the "deleted" attribute to YES and later sync it to the external database that it is deleted. At some future date, all "deleted"==YES entities will expire and truly be deleted.

In prepareForDeletion I want to test to see if:

- dateSynced >= dateModified
- dateSynced <= expirationDate
- "deleted" == YES

and truly delete the object, else:

- dateModified = Now
- "deleted" = YES
- and make it **not** delete

Is there a way to make it not delete at this point?

Or, should I not try to use prepareForDeletion to override deleteObject and just create a new method such as obsoleteObject to set "deleted" = YES and dateModified=Now and only use deleteObject for the purge later?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented such a mechanism very recently.

You cannot delay an entity deletion once it has been marked as deleted. It will be deleted the next time the context is saved. You have to rely on something else to keep things in sync.

Here is my solution. I created a persistent log of events, some of those are delete events. When an entity is marked as deleted, I create a corresponding log entry (in another context actually, which is saved before the context where objects are deleted to ensure the log entries are up to date and saved before the actual deletion is performed). The log is processed later and the delete commands issued to the server. If the log is saved but the deleted entities never deleted because of a crash, the next time the application is launched, the log is processed, the entities deleted locally and remotely at the same time and all is well.

Sounds complicated but it isn't in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't do that this way. I've done this that way - on object deletion I store it's object id (in my case it's guid stored as file) and on sync I push deletes to server.

Answer (score 0):

I would **not** recommend doing so, but there is a way to “undelete” an object from Core Data. It is probably not what you want.

Simply calling `insert(object)` with the object you want to undelete should do the trick. If the object deletion was not saved in the context, you will have to call `processPendingChanges()` first.

**Important**: After the undeletion, you’ll also have to set all of the properties of the object and also undelete all the cascade deletions that might have been applied when processing the pending changes (or when the context has been saved).

Bear in mind this is a dangerous thing to do! You should avoid doing it.

I tested the undelete before a save on iOS 10.